# Re-Calling a react hook after a function is executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am new to react hooks and I have a hook function which receives a series of data from an API to be shown in a list:

```
function useJobs () {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = React.useState([])
  const [locations, setLocations] = React.useState({})
  const [departments, setDepartments] = React.useState({})
  const [tags, setTags] = React.useState({})

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchJSON('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
      .then(setJobs)
  }, [])
  React.useEffect(() => {
....
  return [jobs, locations, departments, tags]
}
```

and I have another function which deletes the jobs when a button is pressed:

```
function DeleteJob (jobid) {
  console.log('deletejob fired')
  console.log(jobid)
  axios({
    method: 'delete',
    url: '/api/jobs/delete-job/' + jobid,
    headers: headers
  })
}

...

export default function Jobs () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [jobs, locations, departments, tags] = useJobs()
  return (
      ...
{jobs.map(job => (
......
 <IconButton aria-label='delete' style={{ color: 'red' }} variant='outlined' onClick={() => DeleteJob(job.id)}>
                     <DeleteIcon />
 </IconButton>
```

the problem is that the DeleteJob function executes correctly and my job gets deleted, but my screen doesnt get updated in real time and it needs refreshing to show the new data. how can I make my `useJob()` hook receive the new data (jobs) after the DeleteJob function is executed?

Comment: Why do you have two `useEffect` calls?

Comment: I have multiple ones, one receives the jobs, the others hold  asynchronous functions for other features based on the job infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DeleteJobs function also needs to delete the job value from state as your data from server is only fetched on initial render. For that you can expose a method from custom hook and use it when calling `DeleteJobs`

```js
function useJobs () {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = React.useState([])
  const [locations, setLocations] = React.useState({})
  const [departments, setDepartments] = React.useState({})
  const [tags, setTags] = React.useState({})

  const deleteJob = (id) => { // function that removes job from state
      setJobs(prevJobs => prevJobs.filter(job => job.id !== id));
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchJSON('/api/jobs/list-jobs', { headers: headers })
      .then(setJobs)
  }, [])

  ....
  return [jobs, locations, departments, tags,deleteJob]
}


function DeleteJob (jobid) {
  console.log('deletejob fired')
  console.log(jobid)
  axios({
    method: 'delete',
    url: '/api/jobs/delete-job/' + jobid,
    headers: headers
  })
}

export default function Jobs () {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [jobs, locations, departments, tags, deleteJob] = useJobs()
  return (
      ...
      {jobs.map(job => (
      ......
       <IconButton 
          aria-label='delete'
          style={{ color: 'red' }} 
          variant='outlined' 
          onClick={() => { 
              DeleteJob(job.id); 
              deleteJob(job.id); // locally delete from state
          }}
       >
           <DeleteIcon />
       </IconButton>

      ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't update after I delete it. it still needs refresh

Comment: Have you defined and called deleteJob correctly? Because if you do, you will se the state being updated correctly

Comment: const deleteJob = (id) => {
    setJobs(prevJobs => prevJobs.filter(job => job.id === id))
  }

Comment: and call it also `onClick={() => { 
              DeleteJob(job.id); 
              deleteJob(job.id); // locally delete from state
          }}`

Comment: onClick={() => {
                          DeleteJob(job.id)
                          deleteJobs(job.id)
                        }}

Comment: can you debug and check if the function is correctly called in useJobs  hook and if you get any error on console

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-ob4gj this is the sandbox for the Job component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214647/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-dorian).